# Edit feature showing different value(Id) than listed value in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular6, ng2-smart-table

I have used ng2-smart table in my angular 6 app. One of its columns has to display access_type, I'm getting it from source using `valuePrepareFunction`. Example. access_id=1,access_type=Type1. So when listing this data in table it is showing access_type correctly but when I'm editing that row using the edit button ng2-smart table provides it is showing access_id and not access_type. Do I need to make any changes to display the same data in edit mode as a display list? Following is my code for that column-

```
access_id: {
        title: 'Access Type',
        editable: false,
        filter: {
          type: 'list',
          config: {
            list: [],
          },
        },
        valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
          return row.access_type;
        },
      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a separate list for editor as you do for filtering.

If you use a dropdown box to edit, that would be ideal as it can use the access_type as the title, and the access_id as the value.

I can only assume this will help you based upon guesses of what your data structure looks like.  Can you give me a sample of what one of the array items looks like?  Do we have a nested object?

Here is a little code to help:

```
    type: {
      title: 'Type',
      valuePrepareFunction: type => {
        return type.abbr;
      },
      filter: {
        type: 'list',
        config: {
          selectText: 'ALL',
          list: this.typeList
        }
      },
      editor: {
        type: 'list',
        config: {
          selectText: 'Select ...',
          // list: [{value: 'access_idvalue', title: 'access_type'}]
          // use the line above to hard code your list, or the line below
          // if you are loading the list dynamically
          list: this.typeList
        }
      },
      filterFunction(type?: any, search?: string): boolean {
        if (type._id === search) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    },
```